# Accordion icon not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This method was working fine until I suddenly noticed it didn't change anymore and I can't seem to find a problem, which is probably very obvious.

HTML:

```
<div class="panel">
                                <div class="accordion-heading">
                                    <h4 data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                                        <span class="up"> </span>Ons team
                                    </h4>

                                </div>
                                <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
                                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                                            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".up").removeClass("up").addClass("down");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".down").removeClass("down").addClass("up");
});
```

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: Not changing the class (= displaying different icon)

Comment: Any errors in the console? What if you `console.log()` stuff? Is the `shown.bs.collapse` event triggered at all?

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/0Ezu7PizGZ I define custom up and down class... And your code seems to work.... Any js error in your debugger ?

Comment: Nothing logged, so it had to be something wrong in my code. Turned out I had too many bracelets... Thanks though